# How would I find a JSON variable without knowing the parent variable names?

Tags: json, minecraft

I need to set the displayName variable but I have no idea how to get to it. For context, I'm making a C# application to set this variable to something else. The parent variables to displayName vary depending on the user that is using this application.

I have blurred these as to not reveal any of my personal information.

[image: Code screenshot.]

I think I might need to loop through JSON object children, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so you are correct you are going to have to iterate over the object and search through to find display name.

I wrote a little function below that will recursively go through the object and search for `displayName`. Obviously its hard if you never know the location or the pathname so you have to have a pretty open way to search the JSON object.

If you can control the way you are requesting the data maybe you could change the format so the data structure is more consistent, but I don't really know anything about where your getting the data from.

This is just one of the many ways to do it.

```js
const obj = {
  authenticationDatabase : {
    accessToken: 'Mock',
    profiles: {
      displayName: 'THIS IS A MOCK USER NAME'
    },
    properties: [],
    username: 'MOCK'
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  authenticationDatabase : {
    accessToken: 'Mock',
    profiles: {
      deep: {
        nested: {
          object: {
            displayName: 'THIS IS A MOCK USER NAME'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    properties: [],
    username: 'MOCK'
  }
}

const findDisplayName = obj => {
  if(!obj || typeof(obj) != 'object'){
    return false;
  }
  if(Object.keys(obj).includes("displayName")){
    return obj["displayName"]
  }

  for(const key in obj){
    if(findDisplayName(obj[key])){
      return findDisplayName(obj[key])
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(findDisplayName(obj))
console.log(findDisplayName(obj2))
```